# Webhooks not triggered for messaging_postbacks

Tags: webhooks, facebook-messenger

I am not receiving Webhooks for messaging_postbacks, when general user, who does not have a role in our App, is replying to our Private Reply message. I have the following advance access permssions: pages_messaging,  pages_read_user_content, pages_read_engagement,  pages_show_list, pages_manage_metadata. I was able to receive Webhooks when role-based user sends us reply. I am also in Live-Mode.
I have subscribed to all the subscriptions required.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.